# How can i get TextView's Default Value in Android Programming?

Tags: android, textview, default

I'm new in Android Programming and Java (and English:) ) . When I study in myself, there were some wrong things. Am i doing something wrong? I'm programming calculator. TextView's default value is 0 (i set this in strings.xml). There are two methods in MainActivity.java:

```
public void Click_c (View View){
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textview1.setText("0");
}

public void Click_1 (View View){
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (textview1.getText().toString()=="0") {
        textview1.setText("1");
    } else {
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText().toString()+"1");
    }
}
```

After program start, i press Click_1 and than textview is 01. But i want only 1. This is work after Click_C.

program start

1. i click Click_C
2. i click Click_1
3. TextView is 1 there is no problem

program finish

program start

1. i click Click_1
2. Textview is 01 Problem is here.

program finish

Answer (score 2):

It's because all time failed at `if (textview1.getText().toString()=="0") {` and go to else condition. So that

You should change

```
    if (textview1.getText().toString()=="0") {
```

to

```
    if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
```

Used `.equals()` method for `string` comparison

Answer (score 1):

**you should first learn about the String What exactly String is so [Go through This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)**

```
public void Click_1 (View View){
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
            textview1.setText("1");
        } else {
            textview1.setText(Integer.parseInt(textview1.getText().toString())+1);
        }
    }
```

use `yourstring.equals(newstring);`

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the string using `equals()` method like this:

```
if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
        textview1.setText("1");
    } else {
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText().toString()+"1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code...

```
public void Click_1 (View View){
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (textview1.getText().toString()=="0") {
        textview1.setText("1");
    } else {
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText().toString()+"1");
    }
}
```

with

```
public void Click_1 (View View){
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
        textview1.setText("1");
    } else {
        textview1.setText(Integer.parseInt(textview1.getText().toString())+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant give plus (15 reputation limit)